# Javascript / How to create an array from an array with only odd numbers?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I use filtering an array of objects

Comment: [2,6,7,34,78,31,89,64].filter(x => x % 2 !== 0)

Answer (score 2):

Use array.filter()

The below should work no problem

```
const oddNums = (array) => {
 const results = array.filter(num => num % 2 !== 0)
 return results 
}
```

Comment: Nice!,  Can further simplify to `array.filter(num => num % 2)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using for loop,

```
 let a = [2,6,7,34,78,31,89,64];
 let b = [];

for(var i=0;i<=a.length-1;i++){
     if(a[i] % 2!==0){ 
         b.push(a[i]); 
    }
 }
 console.log(b);
```